# cordova integrate files into the prject

Tags: node.js, cordova, gradle

Good day everyone; having project and must update to cordova 9.0.0 and at least to android 8.0.0 to publish in google play, when i try to build the build fail because (Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'), the most likely cause is connections errors the question is

- can i set a proxy program (say for example tor) through the node.js command prompt (and not through android studio because it doesn't work)
- if that not possible, if i manged to download the required files manually (example bundletool-0.13.2.jar https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.13.2/bundletool-0.13.2.jar) is there a way to integrate them somehow to the project as a work around

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of attemping a complex workaround, simply focus on fixing that error. Provide more detailed info on the error and the plugins, versions and your Cordova environment used in order to allow that.

Comment: I tried capacitorjs to see the problem in android studio first hand, [Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.jar]

Comment: I can access this file in the browser (using psiphon) but apperantly not in the AS (the https and port num are the same)